# Proper way to set up models and relationships for a rails app, has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am having a hard time getting my head around the best way to set up my models and relationships in rails as I'm need to rails, mvc, and active record conventions.

Consider three tables:

**users**

```
rails generate scaffold User username:string email:string password:string
```

**games**

```
rails generate scaffold Game user_id:integer name:string description:string type:string
```

**game_rosters**

```
rails generate scaffold GameRoster user_id:integer game_id:integer level:integer status:string
```

Users can create games (this is the user_id field in the games table for the "owner").  The creator may or may not be in the actual game (optional record for the creator in the game_rosters table).

Each game has many users which are apart of the game (located in game_rosters).

So I am thinking I should have two relationships for the user - `has_many: games` for the games they have created, and `has_many: games, through: game_rosters` for the games that user is a part of..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :game_rosters
    has_many :games, through: :game_rosters

    has_many :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :game_rosters
    has_many :users, through: :game_rosters
end

class GameRoster < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :game
end
```

But I'm  not sure if this is the right set up, and I can't get it working properly..  I have the above set up, and the following for trying to print results:

```
<p>
  <strong>My Games:</strong>
  <% @user.games.each do |game| %>
  <br><%= game.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>


<p>
  <strong>Participants:</strong>
  <% @game.users do |user| %>
  <br><%= game.user.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

I can print the "My Games" from the `has_many: games` relationship, but can't print the "Participants" from the `has_many :through` relationship.

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<p>
  <strong>Participants:</strong>
  <% @game.users.each do |user| %>
  <br><%= user.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: So I fixed the ".each", and user.name throws an undefined method 'name' error.  When I do user.id it works properly - whats the proper way to access the name from the Users model while displaying from the Games controller using the through: game_rosters relationship?

Comment: @canigetabreak Do users have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Oh wow, sorry.  I have to slow down.  Thanks for the help!!  So my relationship setup up there looks good?

Comment: @canigetabreak lol ok not sure exactly what that means... by glad I helped. :)

Comment: @canigetabreak I see an error in the User relationships, as the `games` is used to define two associations.

Comment: This was my syntax error, but be sure to read @tihom 's answer about my relationship structure - it was spot on, wish I could accept both. Thanks guys.

Comment: @canigetabreak indeed, tihom went deeper into the core of the issue (my response was a bit more "fly-by"). I shall leave it to you to select as the answer the most appropriate choice. If you decide switch answers, I am cool with that.

Answer (score 3):

Also want to add that you should not have the same name `games` for different association in the `User` model.  As last one is overwriting the first. Smthing like this should work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :owned_games, :foreign_key => "user_id", :class_name => "Game"

    has_many :game_rosters
    has_many :games, through: :game_rosters


end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key => "user_id", :class_name => "Game"

    has_many :game_rosters
    has_many :users, through: :game_rosters
end

class GameRoster < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :game
end
```

Accessing the associations for a user

```
 # All the games a user is involved in 
 user.games

 # All the games a user owns
 user.owned_games
```

Accessing associations for a game

```
 #All the users involved in the game
 game.users

# Owner of the game
 game.owner
```

Comment: Oh, thats what I was worried about, if I had the relationships set up properly, I'm going to try your suggestion now.

Comment: So if I'm in the users show view /users/1 and I'm trying to print out the games I'm involved in, how would I access that data?  I can get the games I own by: user.games.each.

Comment: updated the answer. In short, with the scheme I suggested, `user.games` gives the games a user is involved in through `game_roster`  and `user.owned_games` give the games a user owns.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions, but say when accessing the associations for a game I want to get the 'levels' attr which is in the game_rosters table?  I'm having trouble getting to that data.

Comment: `game.game_rosters` returns an array of `game_rosters` associated with `game`. Each element of this array is an object of the `game_roster` table.  So `game.game_rosters.map{|x| x.levels}` returns an array of `levels` for all the associated `game_rosters`.                     It might be good to read the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)